# How to continue a thread if a condition is met or rather another thread has ended?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am new to Java and trying to program a Java 2D Game. Right now, I'm trying to implement that each player rolls one after the other. To implement this, the game loop must wait until the player makes a turn. In this case, wait until the player presses the Enter key to roll the dice. After the player has rolled the game loop should be executed again and then stopped again when it is the next player's turn. I have already tried something like this:

```
public class Game implements Runnable {
    //... 
    public void run() {
        //...
        while(running) {
            //input();
            logic();
            update();
            draw();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void logic() {
        for(Player player : players) {
            player.takeTurn();
            try { wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        } 
    }

    public synchronized void update() {
    //...
    }

    //...

}
```

```
public class Player extends GameObject implements KeyListener, Runnable { //GameObject extends JPanel
    //...
    public void takeTurn() {
        isOnTurn = true
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    //...
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            //...
            isOnTurn = false;
        }
    }
    //...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isOnTurn) {
            continue;
        }
        Game.class.notifyAll();
    }


}
```

Comment: 1. what is `wait()` method? 2. What is wrong with your current implementation? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Amongalen it's `Object.wait()`. But that code won't work since `wait` and `notify` aren't called on the same object (wait is called on `Game` instance, and notify is called on its `class`). In fact the design is wrong, and there really shouldn't be `wait/notify`, `synchronized`, or `Runnable` in there. The AWT event thread and the main thread should be enough.

Comment: @Amongalen I think you should know what `wait()` is ... You've even some answers including it if I remember right.

Comment: @akuzminykh You can never know anything for sure on SO. But for whatever reason I didn't think of `Object.wait()` (maybe cause its early in the morning :) ). I don't think I ever used wait/notify myself, I avoid low level thread management if possible.

Comment: @Kayaman is right your code won't work with how you are using threads. But in this case there is no need for threads at all. Don't use threads if they are not necesary, they are complex to manage and really hard to debug.